# Create interface for array structured data - Typescript

Tags: typescript

From the database, I get the following array:

```
const rawData = [
        [
            426.45,
            10000000
        ],
        [
            426.5,
            66088429300
        ],
        [
            427,
            1000000
        ]
    ]
```

Where **rawData** contains a list of data entry. For example rawData[0] is a single entry with two properties - **rawData[0][0]** is the ***price*** and **rawData[0][1]** is the ***volume***.  Is it possible to create an interface for this entry in Typescript?

Comment: Not an interface, but an array of tuples. Unless you're asking something else.

Comment: You can declare the type for what is shown, and/or you can declare a type for what that represents and then transform from the shown data into the representative data structure, but I'm not certain if that is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: The wording seems self explanatory in this case. OP asked for interface for *entry* where an entry contains the two properties.

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting a 2D array `rawData: number[][]` from the database. You can use an interface like

```js
interface Info {
    price: number;
    volume: number;
}
```

and then convert `rawData` to `Info[]`.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot define an interface describing a tuple (which in Typescript is a fixed-length array), you CAN define a type. This will not get you named elements, but it will keep you from accessing outside of the bounds of the tuple.

```
type RawData = [number, number];

const rawData: RawData[] = [
    [
        426.45,
        10000000
    ],
    [
        426.5,
        66088429300
    ],
    [
        427,
        1000000
    ]
];

for (const [price, volume] of rawData) {
    // price is number
    // volume is number
}

// Type error: Tuple type [number, number] of length 2 has no element at index 2
for (const [price, volume, extra] of rawData) {
}
```

You could then transform your data into an appropriate object model doing something like this:

```
interface Data {
    price: number,
    volume: number
}

const transformedData: Data[] = rawData.map(([price, volume]) => ({ price, volume }));
```